# QNetworkAccessManager не скачивает данные

Tags: c++, qt, get

Пытаюсь запустить простой код для скачивания html-кода страницы, однако ни в отладчике, ни в textEdit содержимое сайта не попадает. Пробовал также другие сайты-аналогично.

```
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QNetworkReply *response = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://qt-project.org")));
    QEventLoop event;
    connect(response,SIGNAL(finished()),&event,SLOT(quit()));
    event.exec();
    QString html = response->readAll(); // Source should be stored here
    ui->textEdit->setText(html);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С указанного домена производится т.н. редирект на другой адрес. Можете проверить, загрузив, например, `http://google.ru`.

Если для запроса требуется поддержка выполнения редиректа, то, начиная с Qt 5.6, это можно сделать, просто добавив соответствующий флаг в атрибуты запроса:

```
QNetworkAccessManager manager;

QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://qt-project.org"));
request.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::FollowRedirectsAttribute, true);

QNetworkReply *response = manager.get(request);

QEventLoop event;
connect(response,SIGNAL(finished()),&event,SLOT(quit()));
event.exec();

QString html = response->readAll(); // Source should be stored here
ui->textEdit->setText(html);
```

Если не повезло и пользуетесь версией фреймворка более ранних версий, то в этом случае придётся включать собственноручный обработчик. Например, такой:

```
void MyClass::get(const QUrl &url) {
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = findChild<QNetworkAccessManager*>();
    if(manager == Q_NULLPTR) manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    QNetworkReply *response = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
    connect(response,SIGNAL(finished()),this,SLOT(onLoadFinished()));
}

void MyClass::onLoadFinished() {
    QNetworkReply *reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());
    if(reply == Q_NULLPTR) return;

    int status_code
        = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();

    if(status_code == 200) {
        // Читаем данные...
        // ... = reply->readAll();

    } else {
        // Перенаправление...
        QUrl redir_url
            = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute)
                .toUrl();

        if(!redir_url.isEmpty()) {
            // Загружаем страницу по новому адресу.
            get(redir_url);
        }
    }

    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

Comment: изумительно!!!!